# No article number in osCommerce?

Tags: oscommerce

I recently installed osCommerce. I now wanted to migrate the articles and cannot find any column in the `products` table matching an article number:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `products_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `products_quantity` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `products_model` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `products_image` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `products_price` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL,
  `products_date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `products_last_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `products_date_available` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `products_weight` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `products_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `products_tax_class_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `manufacturers_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `products_ordered` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Should there really be no default support for article numbers in orCommerce or am I missing something? Of course it is no real problem but a writing task to add article numbers, but I do not want to reinvent the wheel if I'm simply overlooking something.

I'm running osCommerce 2.3.4.

Comment: Please note: "No there is no article number by default" might be a valid answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `products_model`.

`advanced_search.php` reveals that the model shall be the article number, for this columns will be translated to German as "Artikelnummer" (= article number).